# Expression de regret (subjonctif imparfait)

Tags: temps-grammatical, subjonctif, évolution

> Plût au Ciel qu'il eût réussi !

Comment peut-on reformuler cette phrase plus couramment ?

Le but est plutôt d'éviter le subjonctif littéraire.

Comment: Plus couramment ? Je pencherais pour “Putain le con qu'est-ce qu'il a foutu !” Et puis plus sérieusement, c'est plus vraiment possible de dire ça, même en reformulant.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Français vulgaire : Je suis tellement nul :-)! J'aurai voulu seulement éviter le subjonctif imparfait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L'idée est *"ça aurait fait plaisir au ciel (Dieu) s'il avait réussi"* .

Ce qui ne serait effectivement pas non plus utilisé couramment, mais que l'on pourrait remplacer par *"ça aurait été bien s'il avait réussi"*.

Je n'ai pas à ma connaissance de phrase d'expression de regret moderne/courante qui impliquerait le divin (ici le Ciel), si garder ce sens était important pour votre exemple.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Je n'aurai voulu que voir une phrase voisine qui évite le subjonctif imparfait:-)! Votre réponse me convient bien. J'ai modifié un peu votre réponse (si+il => s'il).

Answer (score 1):

On peut déplacer l'idée d'invocation de l'autorité divine chrétienne vers celle d'une invocation d'une autre autorité, presque divine et bien qu'essentiellement païenne avec un statu solide dans la littérature, la destinée. Selon une définition de dictionnaire la destinée est une puissance (souvent personnifiée) qui selon certaines croyances, réglerait le déroulement inéluctable des événements et les lois régissant l'univers.

« Plût au ciel », lorsque énoncé par une personne, exprime un vœux, un fort espoir : « Combien j'aurais voulu que le Ciel soit favorable… »; on ne change donc pas trop l'esprit si l'on remplace la phrase par la suivante, qui a cependant le défaut d'être plus longue;

Combien j'aurais souhaité que sa réussite ait été écrite dans sa destinée!